# Non-Modal JFace Dialog?

Tags: java, swt, jface

Simply put: Is there any way to create non-modal JFace dialog? I've tried calling `setShellStyle` to no avail. If I remember right this isn't a problem in swing - is this a shortcoming of SWT, or am I just misusing the widget?

TIA

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using

```
setShellStyle(SWT.CLOSE | SWT.MODELESS | SWT.BORDER | SWT.TITLE);
setBlockOnOpen(false);
```

seems to be the practice. This doesn't work for you?

Comment: I haven't tried it exactly this way. I will try it and get back to you.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is it, I had another issue going on that was clouding it. Where did you find this practice?

Comment: from [this post](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.swt/msg09439.html) but I have used something similar in the past and has worked.

Comment: Ah man! The difference between googling: 'non-modal' and 'modeless'. Thanks, accepted and +1 for the forum follow up :) Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

```
@Override
protected void setShellStyle(int newShellStyle) {           
    super.setShellStyle(SWT.CLOSE | SWT.MODELESS| SWT.BORDER | SWT.TITLE);
    setBlockOnOpen(false);
}
```

The above code will solve the problem..

Comment: Highly recommend.
Thanks :)

Comment: It will solve the problem but I just want to point out that it is kind of hacky, because you ignore the newShellStyle completely. In a few years you might add a call to setShellStyle() in your application code and you search for hours why that call will not change anything.