# SWT disable window causes lose focus

Tags: java, swt

I'm making custom dialogs that I want to pop up and disable the main shell behind it so that it cannot be clicked while the dialog is active.

My initial plan was something like as follows:

```
shell.setEnabled(false);
doDialogStuff();
shell.setEnabled(true);
```

this worked but as I close the dialog, it loses focus of the shell that was open before the dialog. I managed to sort of fix it by adding

```
shell.setFocus();
```

after the last line but this is messy and causes the screen to flicker as the window loses and then gains focus in a split second, also, it sometimes doesn't regain focus and I can't understand why :/

Is there a better way to disable the background window without it losing focus.

Thanks in advance SO peeps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a custom dialog based on [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDialogs/article.html) tutorial.

This way you just have to set the [modality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796535/non-modal-jface-dialog) of the dialog to whatever you need exactly and the dialog will take care of the rest for you.

This should be helpful as well  (Javadoc of [`Shell`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FShell.html)):

> The *modality* of an instance may be specified using style bits. The modality style bits are used to determine whether input is blocked for other shells on the display. The `PRIMARY_MODAL` style allows an instance to block input to its parent. The `APPLICATION_MODAL` style allows an instance to block input to every other shell in the display. The `SYSTEM_MODAL` style allows an instance to block input to all shells, including shells belonging to different applications.

Answer (score 1):

The proper thing to do is create the dialog as a modal window. When you create the dialog's shell you should do something like

```
dialogShell = new Shell(mainShell, PRIMARY_MODAL | DIALOG_TRIM);
```

Comment: Thank you ! it's meant to be swt.PRIMARY_MODAL but you obviously meant that :D